# "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad credentials"

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing **Oauth2** in SpringBoot RestFul API. Everything is working fine except when I use the **wrong password** getting error response:

**Status : 400Bad Request**

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}
```

But I'm excepting like this:

**Status : 401 Unauthorized**

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Invalid username/password combination"
}
```

[image: if correct password]

**After wrong password:**
[image: after wrong password]

Answer (score 0):

A [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) status would be returned if your authorization credentials are incorrect. This would be your basic auth username and password (in Postman Authorization tab), which appears were unchanged.

A 400 status is returned because the validation of the request's body parameters (username, password) fails to find a match. (ie. Bad credentials were supplied.) It's like other requests where a required parameter is not submitted or formatted correctly.  Your request passes the oauth server's basic authorization for the login endpoint. It would be confusing and incorrect if both scenarios returned a 401 status. 
[400 status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

Comment: I need a solution. Can you provide?

Comment: No, this is the intended functionality for the spring-security-oauth2 library. You might be able to intercept the response and change the status code, but I wouldn't recommend it. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor